# jquery columnizer and display:none

Tags: jquery, html, css, multiple-columns

I'm using jquery plugin [columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) to split a div with text into two columns. It doesn't work properly when the div has property display:none, the same if the parent div has display:none. I know this behaviour is not surprising: the div is hidden so the plugin is not able to count width/height properly. But maybe there could be a way to solve it, knowing that the parent div can be toggled?

HTML

```
<div class="button">
</div>
<div class="parent" style="display:none">
 <div class="child">
  <h1>Title</h1>      
  <p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
  <p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
  <p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.parent').slideToggle(700);
});
$('.child').columnize({columns:3});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I could come up with is to display the parent and hide it after the content has been "columnized"

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.parent').slideToggle(700);
});
$('.child').columnize({columns:3,doneFunc:hidmycont});
function hidmycont(){
    $('.parent').css('display','none');
}
```